# Can't copy file on local share using PS

Tags: windows, powershell

Trying to zip folder on server and save it on another shared folder,

```
invoke-command -Credential domain\Oleg -computername 'server1' {
add-type -AssemblyName "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::createfromdirectory("D:\Folder1\","\\server2\D$\ZIP.zip")}
```

but I'm facing with an error

```
"Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 
'\\server2\D$\ZIP.zip' is denied."
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
    + PSComputerName        : Server1"
```

what I'm doing wrong?
or where I need to add permissions?

Comment: I'm trying to run this command from server2, where I want to store the ZIP file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old "double-hop" problem. There are several, at last count 7, ways to work around this. You'll need to pass a fresh set of credentials inside the scriptblock, in order to pass them to Server2 where you can use them. Zip the file on Server1, then run the copy command from Server2 with the invoke statement and passed credentials.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName 'server1' {
  add-type -AssemblyName "system.io.compression.filesystem"
  [io.compression.zipfile]::createfromdirectory("D:\Folder1\","D:\ZIP.zip")
  Invoke-Command -Credential $Using:cred -ComputerName 'server2' {
    Copy-Item "\\server1\d$\ZIP.zip" "D:\"   
  }
}
```